# how to change xubuntu 18.04 to lubuntu

Tags: xubuntu

How can I change my os from Xubuntu to Lubuntu. Should I download the iso file of lubuntu so i can install it?
Because i find xubuntu laggy when streaming videos on celeron 900mhz

Comment: If you have the disk space, you can add `lubuntu-desktop` to your system, and then select which you want to use for that session at login.  If you find yourself always using lubuntu, you can later remove `xubuntu-desktop`  (this is a variation of @ubuntroll's answer - ie. adding lubuntu first, then the removal later if happy with lubuntu).

Comment: how can I addbthe lubuntu? is that like the procedure for the xubuntu? sorry i am a newbie in terms of these

Comment: As @ubuntroll said; `sudo apt install lubuntu-desktop` will add it (`apt` and `apt-get` do the same thing in this case). The package adds the Lubuntu desktop to your system, including all programs; so you'll end up with `leafpad` (lxde text editor) and `mousepad` (xfce text editor), ie. multiple options that do the same thing.  LXDE default apps will use less memory, so removing `xubuntu-desktop` later maybe useful as 1gb isn't much dram.

Comment: also please note my use of leafpad/mousepad was intended as example.  you'll also end up with pcmanfm/thunar (two file manager), lxterminal/xfce4-terminal, ... for most other applications.   this can complicate menu's, increases your updates (as more software will be updated), and it may make no difference to your complaint.  In testing Lubuntu & Xubuntu releases on ~2004 era machines I found some models great, others not so good because of hardware inside (ie. intel modules/drivers were just better than radeon...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstall `xubuntu-desktop`:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge --auto-remove xubuntu-desktop
```

Many more Xubuntu packages may need to be uninstalled, if they were set to manually installed, but my assumption above makes sense; or you may just not desire to remove them all.

Then install `lubuntu-desktop`:

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: should i download the ISO file of lubuntu when I put that command?

Comment: @Jan No. But it is preferable to do it while not logged into your lxde. `Ctrl`+`F5`, log in, then run the commands.

Comment: @Jan Sorry, I meant `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F5`. And the `F5` is just an example; any number works in the 2-6 range. Then, to turn back to the GUI, use `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F1`. You may need to try some other `F`s.

Comment: @Jan If you need me to add more info, I will, just don't forget to mark my answer as accepted if it helped. It will get my score closer to 50; 50 gives me commenting rights.

Comment: why lubuntu show up in the lock screen (when choosing flavours) even i deleted in the command (sudo apt-get --purge remove lubuntu-desktop)

Comment: @Jan You may need to use `--auto-remove`. Also, check if `sudo apt-get --purge --auto-remove lubuntu-base lubuntu-artwork` uninstalls some more stuff.